# Disabling accounts programmatically

Tags: 6, users, cron

I want to disable user accounts programmatically inside hook_cron() after a synchronisation job. I don't want to delete the users because of their generated content. But they should not be able to log in and receive any notification-mails and stuff like that.

Should I use the user status field for that? And if so should I use [user_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/6) to change this as I don't want drupal to send out mails to the users (via [_user_mail_notify](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/6) inside user_save) or just set the status fields inside the db? Are there any other hooks or functions that I would miss doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Updating status through `user_save()` is a good way of doing it.

Also note that when you set status to a value different from 1, `$op` will get set to 'status_blocked', for which no email will be sent.